How to change polarities of input of voltage controlled voltage source in LTspice
I want to swap the input voltages of this VCVS:

to be something like this:

How do I do so?

Can you select a negative gain like you can in micro-cap? Can you create macro elements in LTspice?

LTspice should have that symbol both ways, mine has them listed as e and e2 in the component selector. Check to see if your installation has both.


You could create your own custom four terminal component which does the flip internally and have your symbol look exactly like you showed. Bit brute-force and comes with caveats if you want to send your schematic to someone else as your custom symbol won’t automatically be included.
